# Is there a way to develop custom haptic feedback patterns?

Tags: react-native, expo, vibration

According to Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines about haptic feedback](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/user-interaction/haptics/), some apps/games call for custom haptic patterns.

How would someone go about doing a custom pattern for an app. Both [`react-native-haptic-feedback`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-haptic-feedback), and [`expo-haptics`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/haptics/) offer an API for pre-defined Apple's and Android's feedback patterns (Different impacts styles, and some notification patterns like success, error, etc). However, they don't offer creation of new patterns.

I am aware of the `Vibration` from [`react-native`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/vibration). However, it doesn't allow for fine tuning patterns using short impact styles from the two previously mentioned packages.

Is there an "out of the box" solution for creating something like this (e.g. two Light impacts, and one Heavy with 50ms pause between them)? I can't find it anywhere.

Apple describes something like this for native developers [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/user-interaction/haptics#creating-custom-haptic-patterns)

Comment: I started developing a custom solution (potentially an npm package) for something like this, but before proceeding, I want to check if there's something that already exists and I'm not aware of.

Comment: Is your solution/package ready? I'd like to use it

Comment: Hi! I published the first version here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-custom-haptics. I'm still working on some features, but should be stable.

Comment: @GrgaMrga this package is great thank you